# Can I share a Microsoft Fakes unit test with a developer using Visual Studio Professional?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes

I'm running VS 2012 Premium and have written a few tests using Fakes. A member of my team is running VS 2010 Professional. After importing my unit tests, he's receiving compilation errors on that the references to both the Fakes assembly - `Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes` - and the generated Fakes assembly from the project reference - `MyProject.Fakes` - don't exist.

Is there to share unit tests with Fakes with a developer who is not running VS Premium or Ultimate? At least so the solution compiles in his IDE?

Comment: If all you want to do is to have him be able to build and run the main app, without the need to run the unit tests, a workaround is to have him turn off the build for the unit tests project in the configuration manager. 

He would then be able to build / run the app, but not the unit tests.

Comment: @user469104 Great idea, but the whole team needs to be able to develop and run unit tests.

Comment: Fakes is only available on Visual Studio Premium and Ultimate.
http://www.visualstudio.com/products/compare-visual-studio-products-vs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good solution, but workaround to exclude only Fakes tests by specifying FAKES_NOT_SUPPORTED conditional constant in the projects on local machines.

Because Fakes are available only in VS Premium/Ultimate editions 2012/2013 and Enterprise 2015(i.e not available in Community and Professional Editions) I wrapped the test methods using shims in #if !FAKES_NOT_SUPPORTED conditions, to allow easily exclude them on Community and Professional Editions

```
#if !FAKES_NOT_SUPPORTED
[ TestMethod()]
public void TestWithShim()
{
}
#endif //!FAKES_NOT_SUPPORTED
```